# How to dual boot Windows 7 and Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7?

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, redhat-enterprise-linux

I first installed Windows 7.
Then I installed RHEL 7 and GRUB is not showing. I cannot boot in Windows 7.
I've searched all over the net but the tutorial I've seen is only in RHEL 6.
How can I configure dual booting?

Comment: From @CRags - Check this website at arch wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Grub  Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever i lose grub after installing Windows OVER Linux, i **ALWAYS** come to this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajs9rO5upZA

Of course, the video is assuming that the Linux Dist. installed is Debian related, RHEL uses `yum` instead of `apt-get` but it shouldn't be hard to translate it to `yum`.